# How to display selected input field from dropdown select on page load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using dropdown select with input text box, here is my code:

```js
function yesnoCheck(that) 
{
    if (that.value == "val1") 
    {
        document.getElementById("adc").style.display = "block";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("adc").style.display = "none";
    }
    if (that.value == "pan")
    {
        document.getElementById("pc").style.display = "block";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("pc").style.display = "none";
    }
    if (that.value == "pass")
    {
        document.getElementById("ps").style.display = "block";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("ps").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<select id="selector" onchange="yesnoCheck(this);">
        <option value="select">__Select__</option>
        <option value="val1">__Select1__</option>
        <option value="pan">__Select2__</option>
        <option value="pass">__Select3__</option>
    </select>
    <label for="selector">Select ID Proof</label>
</div>

<div id="adc" style="display: none;">
    <label for="val1">__Select1 value__</label> 
    <input type="text" id="val1" name="val1" /><br />
</div>
<div id="pc" style="display: none;">
    <label for="pan">__Select2__</label> 
    <input type="text" id="pan" name="pan" /><br />
</div>
<div id="ps" style="display: none;">
    <label for="pass">__Select3__</label> 
    <input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" /><br />
</div>
```

what i am trying to achieve is if any one option is preselected on pageload like `"val1"` eg:   `<option value ="val1" selected>__Select1__</option>`  then the input box is not showing, it will start working only if we select any other value from dropdown. i want to display its default values if any option is preselected on page load. i am new to javascript that's why i am uanble to achieve this. any help is highly appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this you need to check on load also.

java script should be like this

```
function yesnoCheck() {

            var e = document.getElementById("selector");
            var that = e.options[e.selectedIndex];

            if (that.value == "val1") {
                document.getElementById("adc").style.display = "block";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("adc").style.display = "none";
            }
            if (that.value == "pan") {
                document.getElementById("pc").style.display = "block";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("pc").style.display = "none";
            }
            if (that.value == "pass") {
                document.getElementById("ps").style.display = "block";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("ps").style.display = "none";
            }
        }
```

And HTML will be

```
<body onload="yesnoCheck();">
    
        <select id="selector" onchange="yesnoCheck();">
            <option value="select">__Select__</option>
            <option value="val1" selected>__Select1__</option>
            <option value="pan">__Select2__</option>
            <option value="pass">__Select3__</option>
        </select>
        <label for="selector">Select ID Proof</label>


        <div id="adc" style="display: none;">
            <label for="val1">__Select1 value__</label>
            <input type="text" id="val1" name="val1" /><br />
        </div>
        <div id="pc" style="display: none;">
            <label for="pan">__Select2__</label>
            <input type="text" id="pan" name="pan" /><br />
        </div>
        <div id="ps" style="display: none;">
            <label for="pass">__Select3__</label>
            <input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" /><br />
        </div>
    
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Amit. it's easy to put simply another check without disturbing entire code.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this a bit. Just encode the div targets into your options and remove the need for the if statement. Also, it's better (and more flexible) to use css classes instead of styles. This also shows how you can check for it on page load.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  document.querySelector('#selector').addEventListener('change', yesnoCheck)
  yesnoCheck({target: document.querySelector('#selector')})
})

function yesnoCheck(e) {
  document.querySelectorAll('#adc, #pc, #ps').forEach(el => el.classList.add('hidden'));
  let targ = e.target.querySelector('option:checked').dataset.targ;
  document.querySelector(targ).classList.remove('hidden');
}
```

```css
.hidden{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<select id="selector">
  <option value="select">__Select__</option>
  <option data-targ="#adc" value="val1">__Select1__</option>
  <option selected data-targ="#pc" value="pan">__Select2__</option>
  <option data-targ="#ps" value="pass">__Select3__</option>
</select>
<label for="selector">Select ID Proof</label>
<hr>

<div id="adc" class='hidden'>
  <label for="val1">__Select1 value__</label>
  <input type="text" id="val1" name="val1" /><br />
</div>
<div id="pc" class='hidden'>
  <label for="pan">__Select2__</label>
  <input type="text" id="pan" name="pan" /><br />
</div>
<div id="ps" class='hidden'>
  <label for="pass">__Select3__</label>
  <input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" /><br />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot kinglish. you save my day.